# Am I up against an uncrackable UEFI chip on this HP notebook?

Tags: windows, uefi, bootable-media, default-settings

I recently got a new HP laptop with Windows 10 installed and prefered some versatility, so I plugged in one of my many Linux live USBs to get to work. I was greeted with `ENTER ADMINISTRATOR PASSWORD`, even though I didn't set a UEFI password; all I'd like to do is boot Debian from a USB drive.

An incomplete list of what I've tried, spending ~250 hours trying to get past the UEFI Administrator Password with no luck:

- Using all of the typical generic default passwords and passwords suggested by [BIOS-pw](https://bios-pw.org/) from lockout codes
- CMOS:

  - Used `cmospwd` to kill the CMOS memory
  - Used CMOS Deanimator to kill the CMOS memory and the EEPROM memory
  - Manually disassembled the laptop and removed the CMOS battery
- Manually discharged every exposed capacitor on the motherboard
- Physically removed the hard drive

  - Formatted the master boot record
- Windows Startup Repair:

  - Reinstalled Windows
  - Advanced boot options into UEFI
- Device Manager:

  - Uninstalled *System Firmware*
  - Uninstalled all of the processors
- Decompiled entire libraries of `.dll` related to the mystery password
- Decrypted gigabytes of relevant `System32` files from:
  hex, base64, octal, charcode, base32, `xml`, `json`, aes, sha1, sha2, sha3, among others
- Forged certificates from other Windows systems onto Linux bootloaders
- Called HP customer support, spending ~7hrs on the phone with them, with their ultimate answer being "*Take it to a shop and have the offending hardware removed and replaced*"

Comment: Specific model of Laptop?

Comment: Can you disable Secure Boot in the bios?

Comment: @moab it is a 15bs031wm

Comment: No, I can't access the BIOS at all. That's the problem. There's a default administrator password that I cannot crack. I have spent over 250 hours trying.

Comment: If it's a new laptop, you probably got it from a shop. Complain to the shop that they sold a laptop with administrator password set, and get a replacement.

Comment: Do you remember what type of bios it was? Insyde?

Comment: Try this, enter the wrong password and hit enter, do this three times, does it output a code? If so post it here.

Comment: Insyde 52.0. It does output a code, but it's not useful. It also changes every time I re-flash the bios, which yeah not even that is working. I've been modifying archive parameters of the HP-distributed update exe to try and revert into legacy mode. No luck.

Comment: SYSTEM DISABLED

Comment: [i 68315654] is the code, but that method was one of the first I tried. I spent a good twelve hours on that method.

Comment: I have literally spent hundreds of hours trying to unlock it. I'm aware that backdoors exist but I can't find them on the internet. I'm at my wit's end.

Comment: Again, take it to the store.

Comment: GabrielGarcia I bought it on Amazon.

Comment: Just an FYI, an OS or it's system files have nothing to do with UEFI firmware (or BIOS) as neither has access to the motherboard's firmware.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to reprogram the EEPROM chip on the motherboard, as this is where the password lives and is why the password isn't susceptible to CMOS resetting, power outages, or pretty much any intervention short of physical access to the chip; even if you reverse-engineered HP's UEFI updater, you'd have to find a way to get it signed by a trusted cert.

- [Guide to resetting the EEPROM](https://medium.com/bugbountywriteup/how-i-removed-my-forgotten-bios-administrator-password-8dca33844023)
   Obviously, you may need to tweak the process if your laptop model is different
- Alternatively, you can use Fedora on a USB even though Secure Boot is enabled

Answer (score -1):

you can probably pay $10 to get it from http://www.whatsmypass.com/bios-password-recovery-service. They're legit. Or, if you prefer to learn how to do it yourself you can join HPWLab (https://www.egyfixlab.com/laptop/whats-new/). Engineer Osama can help you. He wrote a program called LBE (Laptop Bios Extractor) which can reset the password by extracting and rewriting the section of code where the password is located. It is highly technical. The program costs $105. Each laptop manufacturer is different. Several of the major ones, all you have to do is enter the Bios password three times and you receive a code which you send off to the above. Or, in the case of Dell, they just use the Service Tag to decode the necessary password.